# Windows Menu: MF_HILITE flag does not cleared

Tags: windows, mfc, menu

I have CMenu instance on which I add multiple items.  For one of the items I added in it, I set the MF_HILITE flag.

When I show the menu, the appropriate item get hi-lighted correctly, as requested.  The problem is that it stays hi-lighted until I move the mouse over it and leave.  I only want one item to be hi-lighted at the time.  It seems that Windows does not un-light it when another item is hi-lighed.

How could I force it to be un-lighted as soon as another item get the hi-light?  I could not find any mouse-over callback or message for the menu, and I could not find a invalidate either.

Comment: I know I am using the menu in a strange way:)  I am using a CMenu as a Combobox popup for a particular scenario.  The combobox popup hi-light the current item when it opens, then as soon as the user moves the move the hi-lighted item changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible.

The internal state for the currently selected item in the menu can't be set.  Using the `MF_HILITE` or `HiliteMenuItem` does not set the currently selected item, it only sets the visual style.

As a work-around, I have used a popup `ListBox` instead, which has all the features I need.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `MF_HILITE` in a weird way. The item isn't actually highlighted, it's just drawn like it is. If the user presss enter, the "highlighted" item won't be selected.

You're probably looking for `MF_DEFAULT`.

Comment: I know I am using the menu in a strange way:)  I am using a menu as a Combobox popup for a particular scenario.  The combobox popup hi-light the current item when it opens, then as soon as the user moves the move the hi-lighted item changes.